# My second cascading dropdown doesn't update on the UI when the parent dropdown changes

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have two cascading dropdowns.  When I select the first option, the second dropdown changes appropriately. When I change the first option the options on the second dropdown do not appear to change but change appears on the UI once you click on the stale options in the second dropdown they then become the proper options.

```
HTML:

<select id= 'primary' ng-model="offer.primary" ng-options="XXX.primary for XXX in categories"
                ng-change= setPrimary("offer.primary")>
            <option value="">Primary Business Category</option>
        </select>

        <select id= 'secondary' ng-model="offer.secondary" ng-disabled="!offer.primary"
                ng-options="XXX for XXX in SecondaryCategories" ng-change=setSecondary()>
            <option value="">Secondary Business Category</option>
        </select>

JS

    $scope.setPrimary = function () {
                $scope.secondaryCategories();
            };

            $scope.setSecondary = function () {
                }

    $scope.categories = [
                {primary: "Food and Drink"},
                {primary: "Healthcare"},
                {primary: "Recreation"},
                {primary: "Service"},
                {primary: "Shops"},
                {primary: "Travel"}
            ]

            $scope.secondaryCategories = function(){
                var Secondary = new Parse.Query(Categories);
                Secondary.limit(1000);
                Secondary.equalTo('primary', $scope.offer.primary['primary']);
                console.log('log3:' +" "+ $scope.offer.primary['primary']);
                Secondary.find({
                    success:function(list){
                        $scope.SecondaryCategories = _.filter(_.uniq(_.map(list, function(item){//this function is an iteratee and item is the key word!
                                return item.get('secondary')
                            }
                        ),true))
                        console.log($scope.SecondaryCategories);
                    },
                    error: function(error){alert("A mistake was made.");
                    }
                })
            }
```

My data source is a simple collection where primary is in a column and may not have a secondary relationship or may have many secondary relationships and secondary is in its own column and always has a primary relationship.

Comment: you don't have quotes around ng-change=setSecondary()

Comment: Can you make a Plunker with this code?

Comment: You also don't have quotes around ng-change= setPrimary("offer.primary")

Comment: I don't think that it matters whether anything is in the parenthesis of ngchange. I tried it all ways and it makes no difference.

Here's my plunker code but I can't get it to work on plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gnhX3mRSM1XpZOr88v8k?p=preview